# Using fonts in LuaLaTex

Tags: fonts, luatex

I'm not a an expert in LaTeX in general, but a like to use it. Perhaps my question is naive.

I'd like to use the Chalkduster font as much as possible, and use other fonts for the symbols not available. For example, I'd like my preamble to give the preference:

Chalkduster > Pecita > GFS Neohellenic Math

This means that, for all the symbols not available for Chalkduster, use Pecita symbols, and for all the remaining symbols not available for Pecita, use GFS Neohellenic Math.

Based on other questions and discussions, I use now the following preamble:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,title]{appendix}
\usepackage{dsfont}                     % 
\usepackage{amsbsy}                     % 
\usepackage{amsfonts}                   % 
\usepackage{amsmath}                    % 
\usepackage{amssymb}                    % 
\usepackage{amsthm}                     % 
\usepackage{bbm}                        % 
\usepackage{graphicx}                   % 
\usepackage{multirow}                   % 
\usepackage{mathtools} % 
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\newcommand{\mat}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}


\usepackage[math-style=upright]{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\setmainfont{Chalkduster}
\setmathfont{GFS Neohellenic Math}
\setmathfont[range={\cup,\cap,\approx, \Rightarrow}]{Pecita}
\setmathfont[range={"03C0, "2013-"2014, "2018-"201A, "201C-"201E, "2021-"2022,
                    "2026, "2030, "2039-"203A, "2044, "20AC, "20BA, "20BD,
                    "2113, "2122, "2126, "212E, "2202, "2206, "220F, "2211,
                    "2212, "2215, "221A, "221E, "222B, "2246, "2260, "2264,
                    "2265, "25CA}
            ]{Pecita}
\setmathfont[range=bfup/{Latin,latin,num}
            ]{Chalkduster}
\setmathfont[range={"00-"FF,
                    up/{Greek,greek},
                    \increment}
            ]{Pecita}
\setmathfont[range={"00-"FF, \leq, \geq,
                    \increment}
            ]{Chalkduster}
\setmathfont[range={up/{Latin,latin}}
            ]{Chalkduster}
\setmathfont[range=up/num
            ]{Chalkduster}
\setmathfont{Pecita}[range=\in]

\begin{document}
This is a test:
\[ f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x}, \quad x > 0. \]
\end{document}
```

Just to exemplify, observe in the test above that the minus symbol is not as Chalkduster font.

Can anyone help me to fix my preamble?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Chalkduster.ttf (regular, or upright, text mode) is not a unicode math font. It is missing the relevant open-type tables and the entire Mathematical Alphanumeric Symbols block, for example. `-` is an operator, not a symbol. `unicode-math` has a command to set the operator font.

Comment: Try the `\setoperatorfont` command, but the font does not have the full operator block, either (only 11 glyphs).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried \setoperatorfont{Chalkduster}, but nothing happened. Is that your suggestion or I misunderstood anything?

Comment: Inspection of the font shows that chalkduster.ttf has these operators: `∂ ∆ ∏ ∑ √ ∞ ∫ ≈ ≠ ≤ ≥`. It is not a unicode math font.

Comment: `− U+2212 MINUS SIGN` is not in the font. The Mathematical Operators [256 characters] unicode block = {`∀∁∂∃∄∅∆∇∈∉∊∋∌∍∎∏∐∑ −
∓ ∔∕∖∗∘∙√∛∜∝∞∟∠∡∢∣∤∥∦∧∨∩∪∫∬∭∮∯∰∱∲∳∴∵∶∷∸∹∺∻∼∽∾∿≀≁≂≃≄≅≆≇≈≉≊≋≌≍≎≏≐≑≒≓≔≕≖≗≘≙≚≛≜≝≞≟≠≡≢≣≤≥≦≧≨≩≪≫≬≭≯≰≱≲≳≴≵≶≷≸≹≺≻≼≽≾≿⊀⊁⊂⊃⊄⊅⊆⊇⊈⊉⊊⊋⊌⊍⊎⊏⊐⊑⊒⊓⊔⊕⊖⊗⊘⊙⊚⊛⊜⊝⊞⊟⊠⊡⊢⊣⊤⊥⊦⊧⊨⊩⊪⊫⊬⊭⊮⊯⊰⊱⊲⊳⊴⊵⊶⊷⊸⊹⊺⊻⊼⊽⊾⊿⋀⋁⋂⋃⋄⋅⋆⋇⋈⋉⋊⋋⋌⋍⋎⋏⋐⋑⋒⋓⋔⋕⋖⋗⋘⋙⋚⋛⋜⋝⋞⋟⋠⋡⋢⋣⋤⋥⋦⋧⋨⋩⋪⋫⋬⋭⋮⋯⋰⋱⋲⋳⋴⋵⋶⋷⋸⋹⋺⋻⋼⋽⋾⋿`}

Comment: For syntax of the command, see `4.4.3 Operator font` in the documentation (do `texdoc unicode-math` to open the manual).